# How to globally set implementation class for model attribute data type?

Tags: springdoc

I would like to set a implementation class globally for certain data types. For instance, we would like to stop using annotations throughout our models. Pasted an example below.

```
@Schema(implementation = OffsetDateTime.class)
private Instant createTime;
```

Can we use configure springdoc-openapi to do this? or is there a way to map a Java Instant to OpenApi date-time format?

Comment: Are you accepting the answer bellow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PrimitiveType from io.swagger.v3.core.util.PrimitiveType:

```
static {
    PrimitiveType.customClasses().put(Instant.class.getName(),PrimitiveType.DATE_TIME);
}
```